# Is it possible to specify dictview object as the typing hint in Python?

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting

I'm not sure the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) contains any concrete info on the type of view objects. I wasn't able to locate it (i.e. `<class 'dict_values'>` in the dict's source code. Is there a way to explicitly specify this 'view class'? And does it make sense in the first place? Example:

```
def func1(arg: dictview) -> None:
    pass
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the [`typing.MappingView`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.MappingView) type hint or any of its related types like `KeysView`, `ItemsView`, `ValuesView`.

Answer (score 2):

`typing.MappingView` is now deprecated in python 3.9 , You can use [`collections.abc.MappingView`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MappingView)

```
collections.abc.MappingView
collections.abc.ItemsView
collections.abc.KeysView
collections.abc.ValuesView
```